# Identify the TCP/IP classes respectively by beginning octets

Tags: networking, tcpip, subnet, ipv4

I am busy studying for a network exam and I am stuck with this zinger:

> By studying the following beginning octets, identify the TCP/IP classes respectively
>
> - 1-126
> - 224-239
> - 240-254

The options are:

- a; b; c
- b; c; d
- c; a; e
- a; d; e

At first I thought it's obvious since there are only classes a, b and c.. but the last 2 are not b and c respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In classful ip addressing there are in fact 5 classes.
2. Your instructor, school or study material should have taught you that.
3. Learning classful addressing in order to understand it is valid, but most administrators and engineers deal in classless ip addressing these days (CIDR).

See here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: point (3) is **very** true - address classes are mainly a case of history now.

Answer (score 1):

The class can be determined by looking at the first four bits.  The first octet has the first eight bits, so the class can be determined by looking at just the first octet.  The class boundaries are:
0-127 (starts with binary 0) = Class A
128-191 (starts with binary 10) = Class B
192-223 (starts with  binary 110) = Class C
224 - 239 (starts with binary 1110) = Class D
240-255 (starts with binary 1111) = class E.

The numbers I gave are slightly different: Some people don't like to count the first or last block in a network/subnet, so you should get used to the idea that numbers may occasionally be "off-by-one", as seen here.  Whoever wrote that test question decided to not count Network 0 or Network 255.  Still, the given addresses clearly fit into individual classes.
The correct answer is clearly classes A, D, and E (your final bullet point).

Class D is reserved for a specific purpose: Multicast.  Class E was initially reserved for a specific purpose: Experimentation.  Now it is simply being wasted.  One reason for this may be that some equipment was optimized to support only Unicast addresses if they have a zero within the first three bits (classes A, B, and C).  People decided not to require replacement of that old equipment.  Another reason was some IPv6 proponents wanted to encourage people to start embracing IPv6, rather than delay the migration from IPv4.  So your impression that addresses are Class A, B, or C refers to the common usage: usable IPv4 Unicast communication.  However, the other addresses are considered to valid "Internet Protocol"-style addresses.  For example, 255.255.255.255 is the universal IPv4 Broadcast address, so it is recognized as being an address.  (It is really the only Class E address that is commonly used, and is often handled as a special case that acts different from a typical Unicast address.)

Comment: IP classes have been obsolete for over 20 years! The RFCs killing it were released in 1995. Why, oh why, is classful networking still being taught? It merely places artificial limitations on IP subnetting which confuses many people. I think people should learn how to subnet correctly without the burden of classes. Only sfter someone can properly subnet, classes could be introduced as a historical reference.

Comment: @RonMaupin Why?  As an instructor, I've thought about this.  The reason is because it is good to be familiar with terminology that is still used within the industry.  If someone asks for a Class B RFC 1918 addresses, I would want my graduates to be familiar enough with things to understand that the addresses start with 172.16 - 172.31 and not 192.168.  That's the only really pleasing answer I came up with.  Another reason is that some industry certs still may ask about this (when I checked not all too long ago).  I agree that the current benefits are not nearly as critical as they used to be.

Comment: My point is that someone should first learn how to subnet without the burden or confusion of worrying about classes that no longer exist. Once someone knows how to proficiently subnet, then, and only then, should classes be introduced. I get requests for a Class C or Class B RFC1918 from our `10.0.0.0/8` network space all the time. The requests are not for anything in the `192.168.0.0/16` or `172.16.0.0/12` ranges. The server guys think anything with a `/24` is properly called a Class C.